# Django celery task: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

In Django 1.8, I have this view for users to post in and notify the user's followers of the post using a celery function, but it generates a rather confusing error:

```
 dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Here is the view:

```
  @login_required
    def topic_reply(request, topic_id):
        tform = PostForm()
        topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
        args = {}
        posts = Post.objects.filter(topic= topic)
        posts =  Paginator(posts, DJANGO_SIMPLE_FORUM_REPLIES_PER_PAGE)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            post = PostForm(request.POST)

            if post.is_valid():
                p = post.save(commit = False)
                p.topic = topic
                p.title = post.cleaned_data['title']
                p.body = post.cleaned_data['body']
                p.creator = request.user
                p.user_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']

                if len(p.title)< 1:
                                p.title=p.body[:60]                                              
                    p.save()

                    #notify followers of the new post creation                        
                    title = 'title' #topic.title
                    link = 'bla' #topic.slug        
                    flwd = request.user
                    flwr_ids = FollowUser.objects.filter(followed=flwd).values('follower_id')
                    flwrs = User.objects.filter(id__in= flwr_ids).values('username','email') 

                    notify_new_post.delay(flwd, flwrs , title, link) #<- here the is the problem

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/topic/%s/?page=%s'  % (topic.slug, posts.num_pages))
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/forum/topic/%s/?page=%s'  % (topic.slug, posts.num_pages))
        else:
            args.update(csrf(request))
            args['form'] = tform
            args['topic'] = topic
            return render_to_response('myforum/reply.html', args, 
                                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This happens even before anything being passed to the function (I see nothing happen at celery daemon)

Here is the celery function:

```
#@app.task
@task()
def notify_new_post(flwd, flwrs, topic, link):
    print 'post notification \n'
    subject = 'New post'
    from_email = 'noreply@example.com'
    #to_list = [email]     

    for f in flwrs:

        to_email = f['email'].encode('ascii')
        print "[to_email]: " , [to_email]
        args = Context({
            'flwd': flwd,
            'recepient': f['username'],
            'link': link
           })  
       # if to_email !=[]:               
        plaintext = get_template('myforum/email_new_post.txt')
        htmltext = get_template('myforum/email_new_post.html')

        text_content = plaintext.render(args)
        html_content = htmltext.render(args)

        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to_email])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        try:
            msg.send()
            print "[to_email]: " , [to_email]
            print 'message sent! \n'
        except Exception as e:  
            print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
```

This is very odd to me because a very similar task for a 'topic' view works perfectly well. I've got really perplexed about this so appreciate your hints.

**Update**: here is the traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/reply/52/

Django Version: 1.8.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'registration',
 'aricle',
 'photo',
 'contact',
 'captcha',
 'pure_pagination',
 'emoticons',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_markdown',
 'myforum',
 'userprofile',
 'userpics',
 'djcelery')
Installed Middleware:
(u'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'userprofile.middleware.ActiveUserMiddleware')
Traceback:
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/mypc/myproj/myforum/views.py" in topic_reply
  315.                 notify_new_post.delay(flwd, flwrs , title, link)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in delay
  453.         return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py" in apply_async
  555.             **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py" in send_task
  353.                 reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py" in publish_task
  305.             **kwargs
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py" in publish
  161.             compression, headers)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py" in _prepare
  237.              body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in dumps
  164.             payload = encoder(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py" in __exit__
  35.                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in _reraise_errors
  59.         reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in _reraise_errors
  55.         yield
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in dumps
  164.             payload = encoder(data)
File "/home/mypc/.projenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py" in pickle_dumps
  356.         return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)

Exception Type: EncodeError at /forum/reply/52/
Exception Value: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa traceback added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the fact that the value you pass for `flwrs` is a `django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet`. Django query sets are evaluated lazily, which I'd expect is not good for serialization. Remember that everything you send to a Celery task and return from it has to be serialized. So it is inadvisable to pass anything else than simple types or types that you know for a fact are okay with being serialized (e.g. a class you designed yourself or one which you've checked inside and out to make sure will serialize cleanly).

The minimum fix I would suggest is passing `list(flwrs)` instead of `flwrs`. This would turn the query set into a plain `list`. I would also strongly suggest passing `request.user.id` as `flwd` instead of the user object itself. Passing ORM objects is a sure way to get unexpected behavior. (The Celery documentation mentions this.) Passing an id and reacquiring the object in the Celery task is the way to go.

However, when I look at the code overall, I don't see why the database accesses are performed in the view rather than in the Celery task. So unless there's a line or variable use I've missed somewhere, I'd change your code to pass only `request.user.id` as `flwd` and then perform the database accesses in the Celery task. So the view would invoke the task like this:

```
#notify followers of the new post creation                        
title = 'title' #topic.title
link = 'bla' #topic.slug        
notify_new_post.delay(request.user.id, title, link)
```

And the task would start like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
@task()
def notify_new_post(flwd_id, topic, link):
    user_model = get_user_model()
    flwd = user_model.objects.get(id=flwd_id)
    flwr_ids = FollowUser.objects.filter(followed=flwd).values('follower_id')
    flwrs = user_model.objects.filter(id__in= flwr_ids).values('username','email')
```

(Note regarding the last line: I've assumed that `User` is the user model that is used by your Django project so I'm using the return value of `get_user_model()` (assigned to `user_model`) rather than use `User` directly. If my assumption is incorrect and `User` is something else, then you'd have to use `User` as you originally did.)

Comment: BTW, I use the django User model. So is there benefit to use `get_user_model()` instead of direcly queriying User: `flwd= User.objects.get(id = flwd_id)`?

Comment: If you ever change the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to use a custom model, you'll have to go back into your application and replace all uses of `User` with the return value of `get_user_model()`. For code which is meant to be used internally, it is up to you to decide whether you are okay with living with this eventuality. (I prefer to use `get_user_model()` in my own code.) If you write code meant to be used by others, then you **have** to use `get_user_model()` unless you want people using your code to curse when they find that they cannot change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` without breaking your code.